# How to Make BotAuthentication work with other oAuth Authentication Server applied to API routes

Tags: botframework

I have an API that I'm trying to extend to include a bot controller. I have the BotAuthentication attribute on and everything setup for that.

However we also use our own oAuthServer that is registered and our JWT token decoder is trying to process the BotAuthentication token.

Further even if we handle that, Conversation.SendAsync throws a 401 error saying it isn't authenticated.

Does anyone know how to make the 2 co-exist? I'd rather not have to have a separate site just for our bots.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, I think your `OAuthServer` should only be used to **secure your own api endpoints**

For the **MessagesController**, you should let the **[BotAuthentication]** do the job

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
}
```

or

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity) {}
}
```

Comment: I've tried both these ways and there is no difference. Because of how oAuthServer works it still tries to parse the JWT token using my parser to set the User Identity (which I handle).  But then BotAuthentication kicks in with my credential provider and that works fine, but the Activities of Type=Messages never come through.